# Help with finding the volume of a solid of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Revolve $$ x^2 + 4y^2 = 4$$

> a. About y = 2.
>
> b. About x = 2.

The answer at the back of the book is the same for both
$$
 a.   2\pi \int_{0}^{2} 8\sqrt{1-\frac{x^{2}}{4}} dx = 78.95684
$$
$$
 b.   2\pi \int_{0}^{1} 8\sqrt{4-4{y^{2}}} dy = 78.95684 
$$

I tried splitting the ellipse into its upper and lower half but I still couldn't get the answer. I get that its symmetrical that's why it's multiplied to two but I don't know how you get the equation inside the integral. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rearrange the equation for $y(x)$ in the first integral and $x(y)$ in the second integral?

Comment: I've tried rearranging it,  what I don't get is how you subtract the inner radius from the outer radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About $y=2$: It seems natural to take cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis. A cross-section at $x$ is a washer, with outer radius $R(x)=2+\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}$ and inner radius $r(x)=2-\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}$.

The volume is 
$$\int_{-2}^2 (\pi R^2(x)-\pi r^2(x))\,dx.$$
When we expand and simplify, there is a lot of cancellation, just like in the first problem, and we get
$$\int_{-2}^2 8\pi \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}\,dx.$$
It is a good idea to take advantage of symmetry. So we integrate from $0$ to $2$, and multiply the result by $2$.

About $x=2$: Cylindrical shells seem like a good idea, but we can also do it by taking slices perpendicular to the $y$-axis.

Again we get a washer. The outer radius is the distance from $x=-\sqrt{4-4y^2}$ to $x=2$, and the inner radius is the distance from $\sqrt{4-4y^2}$ to $2$. When we set up the calculation, we get a lot of cancellation, and the result is
$$\int_{y=-1}^1 16\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}\,dy.$$
Again, we can take advantage of symmetry, integrate from $0$ to $1$ and double the result.

The answers **happen** to be the same. We can see this by making the substitution $x=2t$ in the first integral.

Comment: The answer was always going to be the same, right? Given we are not cutting the ellipse, and rotating it about a line by $\theta = 2\pi$, weren't we bound to get the same volume?

Comment: In this case, the answers **happen** to be the same. That has to do with the fact we are using an ellipse, and that special choices were made for the two lines we rotate about.  Change things a little, and we will get unequal volumes.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I'm unsure of the factor of $1/2$ in your equations for the outer and inner radius. At $x=0$ they seem to give 2.5 and 1.5 for the radii, should it really be there?

Comment: The $\frac{1}{2}$ was overenthusiasm (aka error) in calculating $y$ in terms of $x$. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the shell method instead of the disk method? Let's consider the problem b).

The distance from the axis of rotation is (2-x). Considering the top half of the ellipse,
$$
A  = 2\pi\int^2_{-2} (2-x)\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}} \ \mathrm{d}x = 4\pi^2
$$
Doubling this gives us the volume of the whole ellipsoid, $8\pi^2 \approx 78.95$

I will think about the disk method and maybe add it on.